# PHP Splitting Names and Numbers from string

Tags: php

I am having issues splitting a string into their name => number counterparts once I have a string with the number being a part of the string.

For example my function splits these to their appropriate name => value

```
Helium Isotopes 19,533      // Becomes Helium Isotopes => 19333
Strontium Clathrates    22  // Strontium Clathrates => 22
```

But when it gets to this example

```
Fullerite-C540 300        // Fullerite-C => 540
```

It's been driving me insane trying to find a way for it to ignore numbers that are attached to a letter

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: My function is as follows

```
splitNameNumber($str, ' ', ',');// Common usage is like this
function splitNameNumber($str, $dlm1, $dlm2) {
    $chars = array('.','(',')','[',']','<','>','?',"'",'^','*','-','+','\\','/');
    if(in_array($dlm1, $chars)) $dlm1 = '\\'.$dlm1;
    if(in_array($dlm2, $chars)) $dlm2 = '\\'.$dlm2;

    // gets an array with the 'Name-Number' sub-strings from $str
    if(preg_match_all('/([A-z \._\-'. $dlm1 . $dlm2. ']+[0-9]+)/i', $str, $mt)) {
        $re = array();              // variable for data to return
        $max_sub_strings = count($mt[0]);      // number of matched substrings

        // traverse the matched sub-strings
        for($i=0; $i<$max_sub_strings; $i++) {
            // gets separated the Name and Number, and adds them in $re array
            if(preg_match('/([a-z \._\-'. $dlm1. ']+)([0-9]+)/i', $mt[0][$i], $mt2)) {
                $re['name'][$i] = trim($mt2[1], ' '. $dlm1);
                $re['num'][$i] = $mt2[2];
            }
        }

        return $re;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show your function as it is right now.

Comment: helpfull = on topic and not closed

Comment: Show the code mannnnnnn

Comment: Or Womannnn (transgendered or other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s+(?=\d)/', $line);
$value = (int) str_replace(',', '', array_pop($parts));
$name = implode(' ', $parts);
```

This handles all of the examples in your question by simply splitting by spaces that are followed by a number, using the last part of the split as the number, and using the rest as the name.

The names can start with numbers, contain numbers, end with numbers, whatever you need.

Comment: This has worked wonders for me since thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think in this case you might want to use a regex pass to split this string into two parts; the part that doesn't contain any numbers yet, and the rest of it that starts with a number. Consider [the following regex](http://regex101.com/r/zA3rX5/3):

```
/([^\d]+)[^\d.]*([\d\s]+)/
```

And you PHP implementation:

```
$example = 'Fullerite-C540 300';

$pattern = '/([^\d]+)(.+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $example, $matches);

$joined = array($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Example output:

```
Array (
    [Fullerite-C] => 540 300
)
```

Comment: Might want to update it to cater for the comma in the first example as well. Currently it wont work for `Helium Isotopes 19,533`

Comment: Updated. Now presuming that everything after the first number is is a capture group match.

Answer (score -2):

Considering you seem to be looking for a number, look for the space

```
$ro = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$str); // Remove all the whitespace down to one space
$ro = explode(" ", $ro); // Explode into array looking for the space
```